# How we can add a class for the last three item only in a list group

Tags: jquery, html

How we can add  a class for the last three item only  in  a list group.

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li class="last">7</li>
    <li class="last">8</li>
    <li class="last">9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+3) 
{
  color: green;   
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MNthN/)**

Check this out in [this mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-child)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
var $lis = $("li");

$lis.filter(":gt(" + ($lis.length - 4) + ")").addClass("last");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx2zu/3/)

Comment: But then don't use expression as string

Comment: Hai mishik thanks its working but it showing a console error

TypeError: $lis.gt is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$lis.gt($lis.length - 4).addClass("last");

Comment: Anugeeth, yes, my bad. I've changed it to `filter()`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in one line!

```
$("ul li:nth-last-child(-n+3)").addClass("last");
```

(although others seem to have beaten me! I'll post it anyway as a jQuery Solution)

Answer (score 1):

what about just CSS?

```
li:nth-child(n+7) {
color: green;   
}
```

Comment: Dat Internet Explorer....

Comment: what u mean? it d be li:nth-last-child(-n+3)? as somebody suggested?

Comment: I mean it will only work in IE>=9

Comment: true ...but it seems as answer become popular.

Comment: @roasted, not by old IE: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Comment: @mishik ya, sorry misread your comments: IE>=9 my bad ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using slice, passing a negative value to get elements from the end of the collection:

```
$('li').slice(-3).addClass('last');
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjrsc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('ul li').slice(-3).addClass("last");
```

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

```
$("li.last").addClass("last");
```

Here [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjrsc/1/)

Comment: i don't understand the reason for downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote it but that only works because the `li` already has the `last` class. Your code isn't actually doing anything

Comment: thats not mistake, he had also given class for last three li elements.My attempt was to ans the simple

Comment: Yes, to show an example of the output required